# Here a pl-sql function with some defintios for new datatypes , can I get an explination for it

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I can't really understand what's happening in this code , I want to understand it , I tried but it seems like I'm memorizing it instead of understand it .

```
create or replace type t_num_table as table of number INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

create or replace PROCEDURE pro_return_table
(DEP_ID IN NUMBER,
emp_tab1 OUT t_num_table,
emp_tab2 OUT t_num_table
) as
emp_id number;
cursor emp_cursor is select employee_id from employees where department_id = DEP_ID;
begin
emp_tab1  := t_num_table();
emp_tab2  := t_num_table();
OPEN emp_cursor;
FETCH emp_cursor INTO emp_id;
emp_tab1.extend;
emp_tab1(emp_tab1.count) := emp_id;
emp_tab2.extend;
emp_tab2(emp_tab2.count) := emp_id+2;
WHILE (emp_cursor%FOUND)
LOOP
FETCH emp_cursor INTO emp_id;
emp_tab1.extend;
emp_tab1(emp_tab1.count) := emp_id;
emp_tab2.extend;
emp_tab2(emp_tab2.count) := emp_id+2;
END LOOP;
CLOSE emp_cursor;
end;
```

I don't get the first line  also what does it mean to put () after t_num_table , when move from emp_tab1 to emp_tab2 why he moves by 2 , and what should this function to return .
Please any help , I'm so departed.

Comment: [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm#19834)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function constructs two collections of employee id's in department `DEP_ID`.  this function has some problems - for example - if the employee table does not find anything then the first fetch, extend etc will not do anything. 
you can rewrite this function like this

```
create or replace procedure pro_return_table
(
  dep_id   in  number,
  emp_tab1 out t_num_table,
  emp_tab2 out t_num_table
) 
as
begin 

  select employee_id , employee_id + 2 
  bulk collect into emp_tab1 , emp_tab2
  from employees 
  where department_id = dep_id;

exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then
  raise_application_error(-20001 , 'Department ' || dep_id || ' not found.');
end;
```

I have no idea about the `employee_id + 2`. 
This looks like an applicative issue of some sort.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't really understand your target, simple comment the code of the proc for you.

There are no any copying from emp_tab1 to emp_tab2, just filling both collections.

This is a procedure, not function, and don't return any value.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE pro_return_table(
  DEP_ID IN NUMBER,
  emp_tab1 OUT t_num_table,
  emp_tab2 OUT t_num_table
)
as
  emp_id number;
  cursor emp_cursor is select employee_id from employees where department_id = DEP_ID;
begin

  -- Create empty collections
  emp_tab1  := t_num_table();
  emp_tab2  := t_num_table();

  -- Execute query
  OPEN emp_cursor;

  -- Get first value returned by query into emp_id.
  -- Potentially bug because query result set may be empty.
  FETCH emp_cursor INTO emp_id;

  -- Add first element to  collection #1
  emp_tab1.extend;
  -- Put value of emp_id into first element of collection #1
  emp_tab1(emp_tab1.count) := emp_id;

  -- Add first element to  collection #2
  emp_tab2.extend;
  -- Put value of emp_id increased by 2 into first element of collection #2
  emp_tab2(emp_tab2.count) := emp_id+2;

  -- While record exists do actions inside a loop
  WHILE (emp_cursor%FOUND) LOOP

    -- Put next value from cursor into emp_id
    FETCH emp_cursor INTO emp_id;

    -- Add one element to the end of collection #1
    emp_tab1.extend;
    -- Put current value of emp_id into last element of collection #1
    emp_tab1(emp_tab1.count) := emp_id;

    -- Add one element to the end of collection #2
    emp_tab2.extend;
    -- Put current value of emp_id increased by 2 into last element of collection #2
    emp_tab2(emp_tab2.count) := emp_id+2;

  END LOOP;

  -- Release cursor
  CLOSE emp_cursor;
end;
```

Filling first element before cycle is totally not useful and can be skipped.

Filling collection by the cycle isn't effective, use `bulk collect` for that purpose.

Procedure totally unuseful because don't return anything and don't change anything external.